# Building Razor with MvcBuildViews=true failing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, msbuild

I have a new project built up using MvcContrib and MvcScaffold. Everything works fine with dynamic compilation. When I turn on view compilation in the project file, however, compilation breaks.

```
The name 'model' does not exist in the current context
'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'LabelFor' and no extension method 'LabelFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'EditorFor' and no extension method 'EditorFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ValidationMessageFor' and no extension method 'ValidationMessageFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

It's the same kind of errors you'd receive if you [left out the web.config file from the Views folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389055/the-name-model-does-not-exist-in-current-context-in-mvc3), but that's present. I also have [Phil Haack's fix](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/09/compiling-mvc-views-in-a-build-environment.aspx) in already, to no avail. Why isn't MSBuild finding the MVC3 goodies?

Comment: Might be a little late, but did you see http://stackoverflow.com/q/4725387/195550 ?

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had accidentally duplicated the system.web section in my configuration file which caused the same error.