# MVC Application Does Not Load Correctly In Chrome In VS 2013 Ultimate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

i have mvc application and i was debugging it in vs 2013 premium very well in all browsers in my old laptop, but after i installed vs 2013 ultimate on my new laptop, the application does not load correctly in chrome : it does not load css,javascripts ... but in IE it runs very well with no anyerror ...

i am using :

MVC 5.2.0 , Bootstrap 3.1.1

In Chrome's console i can see these strange errors :

[image]

however, i tried to :

1. debug my application again in my old laptop and it loads well.
2. reinstall MVC 5.2.0 and even the newer version 5.2.3 but didn't
   work.
3. clean, rebuild the project but also didn't work.

Note : i published this web application to the web and it works very well in all browsers , so the problem is just about debugging ?.

Edit : i can see now in my views this error appears everywhere where HtmlHelpers are used :

the name 'model' does not exist in the current context

Thanks.

Comment: it can't find jquery. make sure you've defined jquery before other scripts that are using it.

Comment: Check your `Network` tab and see if you're actually loading the resources...and go from there. Hth...

Comment: Thanks. As i saw, all things are loaded but Jquery, but really i do not know why it does not load, because all things are working well in other browsers, i am thinking now about permissions maybe to access jquery ? because it's on localhost ??

Comment: Please, could you see my new edit ?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19696998/1638261

Comment: i changed the version from 5.2 to 5.0 and then error (the name 'model' does not exist in the current context) solved, but the application still cannot load correctly :(