# Asp.NET MVC project with KendoUI MVC helper doesn't recognize HtmlHelper methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I have a very old Asp.NET mvc app, written about 3 years ago and unchanged since then.
It uses KendoUI for user interface, and is built with KendoUI MVC helpers.

At that time (when I made it), all worked just fine.

Recently I had to make some enhancements to it, so I had to update it to latest KendoUI version.

After various minor adjustments, I managed to make it work, be able to build it.
It also works just fine at runtime.

However I have a problem in design mode I don't know where it comes from, which makes it very hard to do any enhancements.

Specifically, in my views and partial views, a lot of elements are underlined with red and reported as error (see below)

[image]

Hovering mouse over any of them, like over HiddenFor extension method, gives a error message in popup as

```
HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for 'HiddenFor' 
and no extension method 'HiddenFor' accepting a first argument of type
HtmlHelper could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)
```

Also, even the **model** declaration is not recognized

[image]

I use VS 2015, and I have the correct reference to

Comment: Could you ensure that you have namespaces added inside `~/Views/web.config`, or `~/Areas/AreaName/Views/web.config` *if you use areas*?

Comment: This is issue not related to  kendo-UI.please check the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696963/razor-view-throwing-the-name-model-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context