# Visual Studio 2017 not syntax highlighting or Intellisense for razors views

Tags: visual-studio

After installing VS 2017 any of my .cshtml files are shown correctly in the editor. I tried uninstalling/installing again and nothing happened. 
I did all options for a similar problem on [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42705738/visual-studio-2017-cshtml-file-errors) without any results.

[image]

Other files are working fine, and I haven't found any other problem in my VS installation. I have the Enterprise Edition with last update.

Comment: Did you see and try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45993416/9533368)?

Comment: Do you see this? Tools -> Options ->Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> HTML Razor Code Background

Comment: Thanks. That didn't worked either.

Answer (score 0):

One time I faced this issue and I tried below steps.

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete the solution user options file (.suo)
3. Re-open the solution in Visual Studio

Or try to delete `ComponentModelCache` from `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache`

Comment: No this didn't worked. I have installed 2017 at least 5 times to test different options. I might have to reinstall Windows from zero.