# I created a project in asp.net mvc 4 and hosted on bigrock

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Am getting below error when I access my website. Am struggling with this error for past 2 days. please help.

Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:

`Line 1:  @model HiProperties.Models.HomeViewModel`

`Line 2:  @{`

`Line 3:      ViewBag.Title = "Home";`

Source File: d:\inetpub\vhosts\indproperties.com\Views\Home\Index.cshtml    Line: 1

Comment: Are you missing the one of the web.config files?

Comment: NO, I have web.config at the root and also inside the Views folder

Comment: Does the error occur in runtime or in design-time?

Comment: it occurs at runtime when I access the website in browser

Comment: Is the .Net Framework installed?

Comment: Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2558.0

Comment: Did you have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696963/razor-view-throwing-the-name-model-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context ?

Comment: yes, but did not help.

Comment: i investigated and reproduce the issue in my system. if i comment the host tag which is inside the web.config file of views folder then it throws the same error. <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

Comment: the iis in the hosting server is not recognizing the host tag. i don't know how to fix.