# The name 'viewbag' does not exist in the current context in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Im using visual studio 2017 and use asp.net mvc-5. My project have error "The name 'model' does not exist in the current context in mvc" at all views

Comment: This might be helpful- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696963/razor-view-throwing-the-name-model-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Razor View throwing "The name 'model' does not exist in the current context"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696963/razor-view-throwing-the-name-model-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)