# Is there a way to get ViewBag, Layout and Model in context on visual studio 2019 for Mac?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, visual-studio-2019

I'm working on a ASP.NET web app and the ViewBag, Layout and Model all say [The name ViewBag/ Layout/ Model does not exist in current context.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7KRk.png)

I have seen some solutions for this problem for Microsoft Visual Studio, but I can't find any for Macs.

Does anyone know a solution for this problem in Mac?

I have attached a picture and also written the code out below.

Thank you

@model WebApp.Models.Movie

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Random";  // Read line under ViewBag here
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";  // Red line under the first Layout here
}

`<h2>@Model.Name</h2>`  // Red Line under Model here

Comment: hi, Sometimes visual studio shows red lines in cshtml, which may appear as error but thats ok. Try running your application and see if it throws any exception. Also  your question " to get ViewBag, Layout and Model in context" is not very clear, so be specific.

Comment: Try these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696963/razor-view-throwing-the-name-model-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context