# Errors in Razor after upgrade from 2.0 to 3.0 and MVC 4.0 to MVC 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have errors showing up after upgrading to Razor 3.0 from 2.0 and mvc 4.0 to 5.0. Does anyone know what changed since then that would give me these errors? My project builds just fine but its just annoying. See the picture..

Error   32  'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Action' and no extension method 'Action' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image]

Thanks!

**edit:**
This problem happens on Visual Studio 2012.
Here are the new errors I get after following the suggestions to upgrade from MVC4 to 5 and downloading "Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012"

[image]

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6507761/2366976) might help you

Comment: *I have errors showing up after upgrading to Razor 3.0 from 2.0 and mvc 4.0 to 5.0* Did you do it right? i.e. get the project GUID correct, the references, NuGet packages etc, [installed support for MVC5 into VS2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx)?